# How to create a range using row and column number and copy that range?

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I am trying to create a range based on dynamic row and column number and copy that range and paste it at another range. I am able to get row and column numbers; but not sure how to create a range out of it and use it for Copy method

```
Sub cut_paste()
    Set TS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table_Schema")
    TS.Activate
    Dim rng As Range`enter code here`
    Dim str As String
    Dim frow As Integer
    Dim lRow As Integer

    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    frow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    rng1 = "A" & frow
    rng2 = "H" & lRow
    str = """" & rng1 & ":" & rng2 & """"

    ' getting error on below line
    Set rng = Range(str)
    TS.Range(rng).Copy
End Sub
```

Comment: Sub cut_paste()
    Set TS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table_Sc`enter code here`hema")
    TS.Activate
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim str As String
    Dim frow As Integer
    Dim lRow As Integer
    
    ' get first and last row
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    frow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    
           
     rng1 = "A" & frow
     rng2 = "H" & lRow
     
     str = """" & rng1 & ":" & rng2 & """"
 


     ' getting error on below line
     Set rng = Range(str)
     TS.Range(rng).Copy
 
End Sub

Comment: If all you want to do is transfer values, there is no need to go through copy/paste. Just assign the `.Value` of the first range to the `.Value` of the second.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need multiple `"` to encapsulate your string and you do not want to create a range from a range (`Range(rng)`).
So, with improvements

```
Sub cut_paste()
    Set TS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table_Schema")
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim str As String, rng1 As String, rng2 As String
    Dim frow As Integer, lRow As Integer

    lRow = TS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    frow = TS.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    rng1 = "A" & frow
    rng2 = "H" & lRow
    str = rng1 & ":" & rng2

    TS.Range(str).Copy
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overdoing the string concatenation and [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) identification.

```
Sub cut_paste()
    Dim TS As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim str As String
    Dim frow As Long
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set TS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table_Schema")

    With TS

        lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        frow = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

        rng1 = "A" & frow
        rng2 = "H" & lRow
        str = rng1 & ":" & rng2

        ' getting error on below line
        Set rng = .Range(str)
        rng.Copy

        'the clipboard has the copied range

    End With

End Sub
```

I've used a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) to reference the **Table_Schema** worksheet as the parent for all cell and range references.